# WSL2 terminal does not recognize Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, windows-subsystem-for-linux, vscode-remote

When I try to execute code from WSL, like this:

```
cmd.exe
wsl code .
```

I get the following error:

```
/bin/bash: code: command not found
```

However, if I execute the same command but first run cmd.exe as an Administrator, vscode opens as expected.

The question is why "code" is not recognizable when I run as non-admin, and how can I solve it?

Additional info: 
WSL2 version 41959
vscode version 1.38
vscode Remote WSL extension version 0.39.5

Comment: Try to run `echo %PATH%` in normal cmd and admin cmd. Did code.exe folder appear?

Comment: C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\bin in both

Comment: Seems the problem is mounting my C drive is working only with elevated privilege. Nothing to do with VS code. If I execute wsl ls /mnt/c I get "ls: cannot access '/mnt/c': Input/output error"

Comment: OMG! "ls: cannot access '/mnt/c': Input/output error" -- is a real bug. See this issue https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/4377 and wait until it is fixed.

Answer (score 33):

As @Biswapriyo mentioned, this is an open [bug](http://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/4377) where WSL cannot access Windows C drive.
Workaround that helped me is to restart WSL like this:

```
wsl --shutdown
wsl
```

Comment: Worked like a charm! Not all heroes wears a cap (:

Comment: This worked for me, too. I guess it is still an open issue in 2021! (I am on Windows 10 Home, version 21H1, windows insider).

Comment: "Have you tried turning it off and on again?"
*me walks away knowing that will fix the issue*

Answer (score 18):

1. Open the PowerShell administrator window

```
wsl --list --version
```

Show as wsl 2

2. Enter the Linux console

```
wsl
```

3. Change related files' rights

```
chmod u+x vscode_dir/code.exe
chmod u+x vscode_dir/bin/code
```

4. Create symbolic link

```
ln -s vscode_dir/bin/code code
mv code ~/.local/bin
```

5. Modify `.bashrc`, add a line as follows:

```
export PATH="$HOME/.local/bin:$PATH"
```

6. `source .bashrc` or restart terminal.

Then you can happily play code in wsl2-ubuntu environment or terminal of VSCode.

Comment: where vscode_dir = /mnt/c/Program\ Files/Microsoft\ VS\ Code/bin

Just doing step 5 and adding this to my path was enough for me.

Comment: I'm getting `ln: failed to create symbolic link 'code': File exists`

Comment: /root/.local/bin/code: 63: /root/.local/Code.exe: not found

Comment: All I had to do was create a symbolic link `ln -s code /mnt/c/Program\ Files/Microsoft\ VS\ Code/bin/code`.  The `code` link was placed somewhere in the path.  I did not need to mark those files executable, they already were.

Answer (score 1):

My problem was that I was using the root user after running `sudo -i`. Exiting and using my normal user on WSL solved the error.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I am using Debian and echo %PATH% did not output anything.

I used the second part of suggested solution from [resolved github issue](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/5779)

```
For Debian, /etc/profile contributed to this problem.

Here is the path definition in /etc/profile

if [ "`id -u`" -eq 0 ]; then
  PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin"
else
  PATH="/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games"
fi
```

Option 1:

```
You can delete above lines, then wsl --shutdown to restart Debian.
```

Option 2:

```
If you would like to keep these lines, you can also append ":$PATH" to each path like below, then wsl --shutdown

if [ "`id -u`" -eq 0 ]; then
  PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:$PATH"
else
  PATH="/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games:$PATH"
fi
```

Thank you to [licanchua](https://github.com/licanhua)

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend checking `/etc/wsl.conf` to see if `appendWindowsPath` setting shares the Windows PATH with WSL, and also if it is specifically setting a particular user.

For the config settings, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/wsl-config